# How to join databases in mongoDB and fetch the required result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have somewhat of the following type of database -

```
var school= mongoose.model('School' ,{
    name : { type : String, minlength : 1, trim : true },
    email : { type : String, trim : true },
    password : { type : String, minlength : 8, },
    mobile : { type : Number, minlength : true },
    address : { type : String },
    description : { type : String },
    student : { type : Array },
});
```

My site is home to many schools so the students should be able to see only the students of the same school. For this I have created a different table for the students and entering their unique values in the **Student Array in School DB** along with the respective student DB. How should I be able to fetch **all the Student's data**  if i have student array from School DB.....

Comment: Get the School model to have the school.student Array then you must query the collection "Student" and us $in operator. Kind of student.find({_id: {$in: school.student}}). You can also use Aggregation Framework and use $lookup to joins the documents.